# How to print an object element inside an array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, puts

I have to print in shell the description of my error, and I can't access to the element inside an object inside an array and I'm still learning Ruby.

I've tried

```
rescue => e
  puts e.fields[description]
...
```

and doesn't work.

```
{
  "code": "123",
  "message": "Invalid data.",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "test",
      "description": "testing"
    }
  ]
}
```

---> I want to print only `testing`

Thank you

so much for your help :)

Comment: try this: `e[:fields].first[:description]`

Comment: You show `e` as if it is a hash, is that the case? Or are `code`, `message` and `fields` methods of `e`? (because that seems more appropriate for an error-object --but it could well be the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

`h = {:code=>"123", :message=>"Invalid data.", :fields=>[{:name=>"test", :description=>"testing"}]}`

then

`h.dig(:fields, 0, :description)`

Answer (score 1):

```
e["fields"].each do |field|
 puts field["description"]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this - e[:fields][0][:description]

Answer (score 0):

In your response fields, the key is containing an array object.

If you want to print the specific value then you need to use an index like this `e["fileds"][0]` then this will print "testing".

If you want to print all the description then you should do like this:

```
e["fileds"].each do |field|
   puts field["description"]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If `e` is a `Hash`, as one could deduce from the way you show the contents of `e`,
you could write

```
e["fields"][0]["description"]
```

As usual in Rails there are many ways to achieve the same, and sometimes *not*.

You could also write `e[:fields][0][:description]` but only if the `Hash` *has indifferent access*, which means you can use strings and symbols interchangeably (that is by default, if you create a hash yourself, *not* the case).

So to explain the line in more detail: `e["fields"]` returns an array (of hashes), take the first element: `e["fields"][0]` or `e["fields"].first` and then get the value for the key `description` in the hash.

However, if you created a class that inherited from `StandardError` which is what is usually thrown on error, you would most likely have to write something like:

```
 e.fields
```

which returns the array of fields. To find the first element, we write, again `e.fields[0]` or `e.fields.first`, and then it depends if the array contains hashes, or objects with a method `description`, so it could either be

```
e.fields[0].description
```

or

```
e.fields[0][:description]
```

(I prefer to write the symbol key, but please remember if your Hash has strings as keys and is not a `HashWithIndifferentAccess` you will have to use the string `"description"`)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the comma separated descriptions

```
descriptions = e["fields"].map{|f| f["description"]}.join(',')
puts descriptions
```